# How do I reset code color scheme to default in Dreamweaver CS5 (Windows)?

Tags: colors, settings, dreamweaver

I have read **[this post](http://adobe.ly/rbQRTq)**, but the process is not clear, I don't find the **CodeColoring** folder.

So, how to reset code color scheme to default in **Dreamweaver CS5 (Windows)**?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The original folder referred to in that link is located at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5\configuration` (64 bit OS)
or
`C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5\configuration` (32 bit OS)

Copy the "CodeColoring" folder there and paste it here:

```
C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver CS5\en_US\Configuration
```

That will reset DW to default code coloring.  Alternately you can rename the User Configuration folder to Configuration.old and DW will rebuild it on next launch and reset all preferences to default...

Comment: Hello **JCL1178**: It works. Thanks a lot. I had to reset the Dreamweaver color scheme because I tried to change the JavaScript color scheme to dark scheme, but it still showing me some characters in black color after I change all its options to light colors. I can't read it easily.

Comment: +1 works on CS6 too, just don't forget to manually reset Default background.

Answer (score 2):

I created a Dreamweaver color theme editor, you can use it to restore the default theme, or create your own theme starting with the default theme or a dark theme I made that's designed to make it easy to transition to a dark theme.

You can edit 18 different colors, and then you can download an xml file that replaces the current one. It takes care of all the redundant color settings. It also has instructions for how to install the theme. Super easy.

Try it out! http://inorganik.net/dw-color-theme-editor

Comment: If you have any problems using this tool to restore your default theme or install a new theme - let me know with a comment here, I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get Dreamweaver CC to colorize Coldfusion Coding:

```
c:\system...
user...
attuid file...
AppDate...
Roaming...
Adobe...
Dreamweaver CS5.5 or Dreamweaver CS6...
en_US...
Configuration...
ColorCoding...
Color.xml...
open in text editor...
Copy this block...
colorGroup doctypes="ColdFusion"..../colorGroup doctypes="ColdFusion"
and
colorGroup doctypes="CSS" .... /colorGroup doctypes="CSS"
```

Paste to

```
c:\system...
user...
attuid file...
AppDate...
Roaming...
Adobe...
Dreamweaver CC 2014...
en_US...
Configuration...
ColorCoding...
Color.xml...
```

we will have to maintain colorizing coldfusion code tags in
Dreamweaver CS5.5 or CS6 and copy/paste the code blocks up into CC 2014

Comment: I'm using CC and one of my colleagues has CS5.5, however his Colors.xml only contains the `<colorGroup>` with no doctype. Any chance you can provide the `syntaxColor` and `tagColor`  ids I should use for ColdFusion? I found `CFCommentText` but that's it so far!