# Reset Dreamweaver CS5 coloring scheme

Tags: dreamweaver

I had been modifying my HTML code coloring scheme in Dreamweaver CS5 via

Edit > Preferences > Code Coloring > Edit Coloring Scheme

and now it looks terribad, how do I reset it back to the default settings?

Comment: If you're in Windows deleting/moving the file Documents and Settings\YOURNAME\Application Data\Adobe\Dreamweaver CS5.5\en_US\Configuration\CodeColoring\Colors.xml may work.(Note that the user's profile path is Users\YOURNAME in Windows Vista/7)

Comment: Windows. There's also a group of XML files here, which colors.xml file should I modify? C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5\configuration\CodeColoring\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you can find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272847/how-to-reset-code-color-scheme-to-default-in-dreamweaver-cs5-windows). It is a same question.

You need to restore code coloring files.
The original folder referred to in that link is located at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5\configuration (64 bit OS) or C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5\configuration (32 bit OS)

Copy the "CodeColoring" folder there and paste it here:

C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver CS5\en_US\Configuration

EDIT:
Or you can view [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/839/cpsid_83912.html) how to restore preferences in Dreamweaver CS4/CS5

Comment: Excellent writeup!! Worked like a charm. Also noticed most of the settings are in that same \en_US\ directory so useful for more than just color schemes.

Answer (score -2):

What about a [dark color scheme for Dreamweaver's code view](http://thatwebguyblog.com/show_article.php?id=2651)? It's not the default color scheme but I think it's a ton better. You can also find the default Dreamweaver colors there if dark is not to your taste.

Comment: that doesn't work. the file he posted to restore the "default Dreamweaver colors" is the same as his modified color scheme! HAHA! maybe someone else with an unmodified colors.xml in their Dreamweaver CS5 install can post a link